# Can you access a Modules Quick Settings from a Scheduled Task

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Can you access a Modules Quick Settings from a scheduled task (class implementing SchedulerClient)? OR is there a way to select which Module you would like to retrieve the ModuleSettings for?

for example:

```
ActiveModule.ModuleSettings[FeatureController.SETTING_URL]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the module settings with the `ModuleController`.

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;

//get the module settings with the correct ModuleId and TabId
ModuleInfo mi = ModuleController.Instance.GetModule(ModuleId, TabId, false);

//change some settings
mi.ModuleTitle = "New Module Title";

//save the new module settings
ModuleController.Instance.UpdateModule(mi);
```

UPDATE

You can get all the Tabs or Modules like this

```
//get all tabs in the portal
var tabs = TabController.GetPortalTabs(PortalId, 0, true, false);

//get all modules in the portal
var modules = ModuleController.Instance.GetModules(PortalId);

//loop all individual modules
foreach (ModuleInfo module in modules)
{
     Label1.Text += module.ModuleTitle + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: is there a way to dynamically get a modulesId and TabId without having to manually query the database?